# Can I hang shelves on painted walls without using penetrating fasteners?

Tags: shelving

I live in a **40 m2** apartment with 2 cats.

I was thinking maybe I can add shelves to the walls without drilling anything. Do you think that sticking shelves can whitsand the weight of a 6kg and 4 kg cats? Have you done that before? I want to go as high as 2 meters.

Comment: You probably could do it.  Liquid nails and other adhesives can be stronger than fasteners.  I can't image why you'd want to do it that way.  Removing it from the wall depending on the material would be way more destructive and setting up the shelving until the adhesive cures would take a lot of work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bond will fail at the weakest point in the layers between your shelf and the actual structure of the wall.
Many people fail to account for the fact that paint really isn't intended to be subject to those kinds of forces and are surprised when it all peels off.

I predict that you'll end up with shelves fallen to the floor with the paint peeled off the wall and still stuck to the back of the shelves.

It's *far* easier to repair the holes from a few neat screws than it would be to repair the unknown level of damage which may occur when your shelves start pulling layers off the wall in unexpected ways.

Having more than a handful of cats myself, I know how active the little fur-balls can be - and those shelves will end up seeing dynamic loads far in excess of the 4-6kg the beasties actually weigh.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it using double sided tape from 3M. It held for a while but eventually failed due to the cats jumping up and landing on them. Once the double sided tape pulled away from the wall, it did more damage than if I had just screwed a bracket into the wall for the shelves. Good luck. F.Y.I. Cats don't always land on their feet.

Answer (score 1):

To add to other answers, consider that when a 6kg animal lands or jumps on a shelf, the force can be double or more than their mass, and include sideways vector forces too (I asked a cat.)

Get shelf brackets, and try to locate a stud, at least one, to attach to. If you can’t screw into the walls no matter how minimally invasive, consider a storage unit that sits on the floor, one that looks like a group of geometric shapes (boxes.) Set thin shims under the front part on the floor so the unit leans into the wall slightly. It’ll be less likely to fall over that way. Again, double sided tape or surface gluing won’t last for long.

Comment: oh you asked a cat LOL

Comment: I agree that going with a floor-standing bookcase would be better -- and if the OP has existing furniture along that wall, find one which is designed such that the first shelf is way up high.

Comment: Had to tickle her feet to get an answer. A surface with a bit of texture will let them plant their landings without slipping  off